# How do I wrap a java.util.concurrent.Future in an Akka Future?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, akka, future

In a Play Framework 2.0.1 (Scala) application, we are using a web service client library which returns `java.util.concurrent.Future` as responses.

Instead of blocking the Play app on the `get()` call, we'd like to wrap the `j.u.c.Future` in an `akka.dispatch.Future`, so that we can easily use the play framework's `AsyncResult` processing.

Has anyone done this before, or have a library or example code?

---

**UPDATE**: The closest thing we've found is this google groups discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/c4DOOtGF50c

> ...if all you have is a plain j.u.c.Future the best you can do to create a non blocking solution is to take the j.u.c.Future and a Promise, and give them to some thread running a polling loop that will complete the Promise with the result of the Future when it is done.

Does anyone have an example implementation of this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@Viktor Klang: We understand that `j.u.c.Future` is an abomination. But that's what we're getting back from a piece of software we must accept as given for the time being.

So far, this is what we've hacked together:

```
def wrapJavaFutureInAkkaFuture[T](javaFuture: java.util.concurrent.Future[T], maybeTimeout: Option[Duration] = None)(implicit system: ActorSystem): akka.dispatch.Future[T] = {
  val promise = new akka.dispatch.DefaultPromise[T]
  pollJavaFutureUntilDoneOrCancelled(javaFuture, promise, maybeTimeout.map(_.fromNow))
  promise
}
```

In other words, create a separate Akka `Promise` (the write-side of a `Future`) corresponding to the `j.u.c.Future`, kicks off the callback `pollJavaFutureUntilDoneOrCancelled` to update the Promise by polling the "abomination", and returns the Promise to the caller.

So how do we "poll" to update the Akka Promise based on the state of the j.u.c.Future?

```
def pollJavaFutureUntilDoneOrCancelled[T](javaFuture: java.util.concurrent.Future[T], promise: akka.dispatch.Promise[T], maybeDeadline: Option[Deadline] = None)(implicit system: ActorSystem) {
  if (maybeDeadline.exists(_.isOverdue)) javaFuture.cancel(true);

  if (javaFuture.isDone || javaFuture.isCancelled) {
    promise.complete(allCatch either { javaFuture.get })
  } else {
    Play.maybeApplication.foreach { implicit app =>
      system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(50 milliseconds) {
        pollJavaFutureUntilDoneOrCancelled(javaFuture, promise, maybeDeadline)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is an attempt at what was hinted at in the google groups discussion that I referenced in the question. It uses the Akka scheduler to call itself back every 50 ms to check if the j.u.c.Future is either done or cancelled. Whenever that happens, it updates the Akka Promise with the completed state.

@Victor Klang, et al:

Is this best practice? Do you know of a better way to do this? Are we missing a downside here that we should know about?

Thanks for any more help.

Comment: One obvious downside is, that in the worst case this will cause a high delay of the response. If you have for example the default settings and your future completes 1 ms after the check, it can cause a delay of about 100ms. This can however be adjusted by setting the `scheduler.tick-duration` setting in the config.

Comment: @drexin true, but a tick duration and poll frequency trade-off will be present in any polling based solution, right?

Comment: Sure, but as you asked for downsides I just wanted to tell you, that it does not only depend on the delay param of the `scheduleOnce` call, but also on the setting in the akka config. If you can live with a delay this should be a usable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `akka.dispatch.Futures.future()` with `java.util.concurrent.Callable`:

```
val akkaFuture: akka.dispatch.Future[String] = akka.dispatch.Futures.future(
  new java.util.concurrent.Callable[String] {
    def call: String = {
      return "scala->" + javaFuture.get
    }
}, executionContext)
```

[Gist for complete example](https://gist.github.com/huljas/07eb777f6e6d3c6e7d1f)

Comment: This essentially results in more threads than necessary, one of which blocks, and is not any better than simply calling javaFuture.get on the main thread. Introducing akka future is not beneficial here except in extreme situations where component compatibility is absolutely needed.