# Should infrastructure like Akka be used to wrap blocking calls (to a relational DB)?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, playframework, akka

I've read a lot about event-driven programming on the server side, mostly, related to Akka and Play. I understand the potential benefits for reducing the number of active threads. Yet, I can't wrap my head around a particular scenario:

Imagine that one of my actors has to execute a DB operation, using blocking jdbc. If we follow the simple assumption of one thread per actor,  that means that subsequent calls to the DB will be executed in a very synchronous fashion. Although the thread consumption won't rise, it seems that the approach is very impractical,  because a client will have to wait an increasingly large amount of time, before obtaining the response of the DB.

Here comes the dedicated thread pool. Instead of running a thread per actor, we can run a limited number of threads, dedicated to DB access. Although this approach evades the basic proposition of running one thread per actor, it is certainly possible.

Yet,  in the general sequence of events,  I don't see the real benefit of this approach,  for a project,  where 90% of the client requests require some access to the DB. Indeed, the controller/application logic will run on a single thread, but the data access logic won't. At the end, I'm asking myself how that's different from running a thread pool for the application itself, and simply serving every request in its own thread.

Please, prove me if I am wrong, but my math speaks otherwise. Why would you take this scenario?

Answer (score 2):

This is a very general question, but here is some food for your thoughts:

- Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094568/best-practices-with-akka-in-scala-and-third-party-java-libraries/25094875#25094875), if you want to know, how one typically deals with blocking APIs in a non-blocking application.
- You don't say it explicitly, but i have the impression that you mainly think about performance reasons for a non blocking approach. This is not the most important part. In my opinion the most important reason for a non blocking approach is **failure tolerance**. The [reactive manifesto](http://www.reactivemanifesto.org/) calls it **resilience**. If you follow the approach from the question i linked, you are able to achieve this ability within your application. Asynchronous operations enable you to compartmentize your app.
- You generically say that DB operations are blocking. You are right that *JDBC* is blocking. But SQL isn't the only type of database available today. Think of **NoSQL solutions** like MongoDB that **provide non-blocking clients**. And todays applications typically use a lot of web service internally, which can be consumed in a non blocking fashion easily. So most of the time your non blocking application should not consist of 90% blocking calls.

**TLDR:** Performance is not important. Resilience is :)