# How use dao pattern with akka?

Tags: java, scala, akka, load-balancing, dispatcher

I have read about [akka dispatchers](https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/dispatchers-and-routers). So in general Pinned dispatcher is useful with long running tasks, while simple
Dispatcher is better for smaller. So consider a classical dao interface (written in java):

```
public interface Dao<Client> {
    public Client insertOne(Client client);
    public Client insertBatch(Collection<Client> client);
}
```

So `insertOne` is small task, while `insertBatch` is long running. So is it a good practice to create to separate actors
for each operation and using different dispatcher for them? For example *Dispatcher* to `InsertOneClientActor` and *Pinned dispatcher* for
   `InsertBatchClientsActor`?

Or I should not use a classical dao pattern and create several actors (one  actor per db operation) with db access (connection) which will be responsible for it's own one db peration? And also configure dispatcher according to db operation weigh?

Comment: I would suggest to use `Future`-s for long-running and/or blocking operations. You can pass such `Future`-s to another actors and use a dedicated `ExecutionContext` for them.

Comment: If you want to read more about the approach with `Future`s =, have look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094568/best-practices-with-akka-in-scala-and-third-party-java-libraries/25094875#25094875